# SQLAlchemy session cleared in celery job and on_success function

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a tool that fetches data from a different database, transforms it, and stores it in my own database. I'm migrating from APScheduler to Celery, but I ran into the following problem:

I use a class I call `JobRecords` to store when a job ran, whether it was successful and which errors it encountered. I use this to know not too look too far back for updated entries, especially since some tables have multiple millions of rows.

Since the system is the same for all jobs, I created a subclass from the celery `Task` object. I make sure the job is executed within the Flask app context, and I fetch the latest time this Job finished successfully. I also make sure I register a value for `now` to avoid timing issues between querying the database and adding the job record.

```py
class RecordedTask(Task):
  """
  Task sublass that uses JobRecords to get the last run date
  and add new JobRecords on completion
  """
  now: datetime = None
  ignore_result = True

  _session: scoped_session = None
  success: bool = True
  info: dict = None

  @property
  def session(self) -> Session:
    """Making sure we have one global session instance"""
    if self._session is None:
      from app.extensions import db
      self._session = db.session
    return self._session

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from app.models import JobRecord

    kwargs['last_run'] = (
        self.session.query(func.max(JobRecord.run_at_))
        .filter(JobRecord.job_id == self.name, JobRecord.success)
        .first()
    )[0] or datetime.min
    self.now = kwargs['now'] = datetime.utcnow()

    with app.app_context():
      super(RecordedTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

  def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args: list, kwargs: dict, einfo):
    self.session.rollback()
    self.success = False
    self.info = dict(
        args=args,
        kwargs=kwargs,
        error=exc.args,
        exc=format_exception(exc.__class__, exc, exc.__traceback__),
    )
    app.logger.error(f"Error executing job '{self.name}': {exc}")

  def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args: list, kwargs: dict):
    app.logger.info(f"Executed job '{self.name}' successfully, adding JobRecord")

    for entry in self.to_trigger:
      if len(entry) == 2:
        job, kwargs = entry
      else:
        job, = entry
        kwargs = {}
      app.logger.info(f"Scheduling job '{job}'")
      current_celery_app.signature(job, **kwargs).delay()

  def after_return(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from app.models import JobRecord
    record = JobRecord(
        job_id=self.name,
        run_at_=self.now,
        info=self.info,
        success=self.success
    )
    self.session.add(record)
    self.session.commit()
    self.session.remove()
```

I added an example of a job to update a model called `Location`, but there are a lot of jobs just like this one.

```py
@celery.task(bind=True, name="update_locations")
def update_locations(self, last_run: datetime = datetime.min, **_):
  """Get the locations from the external database and check for updates"""
  locations: List[ExternalLocation] = ExternalLocation.query.filter(
      ExternalLocation.updated_at_ >= last_run
  ).order_by(ExternalLocation.id).all()

  app.logger.info(f"ExternalLocation: collected {len(locations)} updated locations")
  for update_location in locations:
    existing_location: Location = Location.query.filter(
        Location.external_id == update_location.id
    ).first()

    if existing_location is None:
      self.session.add(Location.from_worker(update_location))
    else:
      existing_location.update_from_worker(update_location)
```

The problem is that when I run this job, the `Location` objects are not committed with the `JobRecord`, so only the latter is created. If I track it with the debugger, `Location.query.count()` returns the correct value inside the function, but as soon as it enters the `on_success` callback, it's back to 0, and `self._session.new` returns an empty dict.

I already tried adding the session as a property to make sure it's the same instance everywhere, but the problem still persists. Maybe it has something to do with it being a `scoped_session` because of `Flask-SQLAlchemy`?

Sorry about the large amount of code, I did try to strip as much away as possible. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the culprit was the combination of `scoped_session` and the Flask app context. Like any contextmanager, running the code `with app.app_context()` triggered the `__exit__` function on leaving, which in turn caused the `ScopedRegistry`, where the `scoped_session` was stored, to be cleared. Then, a new session was created, the `JobRecords` were added to that, and that session was committed. Therefore, the locations would not be written to the database.

There are two possible solutions. If you don't use sessions in other files than in your task, you can add a session property to the task. This way, you avoid the `scoped_session` alltogether, and can clean up in your `after_return` function.

```py
 @property 
 def session(self):
   if self._session is None:
      from dashboard.extensions import db
      self._session = db.create_session(options={})()
    return self._session
```

However, I was accessing the session in my model definition files as well, through `from extensions import db`. Therefore, I was using two different sessions. I ended up using `app.app_context().push()` instead of the contextmanager, thus avoiding the `__exit__` function

```py
  app.app_context().push()
  super(RecordedTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```